# How come I'm getting a "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: botframework, http-status-code-405

I'm attempting to use the Microsoft Bot Framework with a simple Q/A scenario. I followed the steps found on the [Getting Started with Connector](http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html) page. However, after I register my bot and upload it I'm getting a Method Not Allowed error when I test it on the bot framework site. I can run the bot in the emulator just fine. I understand that it's an 405 error but what I don't understand is what call is it trying to do. Does anyone know?

[Method Not Allowed Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOsJ4.png)

Comment: Does it work on any channels? I've had problems with the *Test connection* thing before. You could try to remote debug it and see the code flow after clicking that button.

Comment: So far I have tested it on the webchat but that is broken too. I'll enable remote debugging and see what's going on.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add **/api/messages** at the end of the **Messaging endpoint** of **Configuration** settings.

Like:

> your_bots_hostname/api/messages

[image]